# ngmodel does not get changed in frontend

Tags: angularjs

I have property called count which is attached to view through ng-model. To be exact, ng-model is inserted in  HTML element. Meaning that, users can change value of count property.

**AngularJS Controller Part**

```
app.controller("QuizController", ['$scope' function (scope) 
{
  $scope.count = 1;

  $scope.pageLocatorChange = function()
  {
       $scope.count = this.count;
  }

  $scope.increment = function()
  {
      $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
  }

}
```

**HTML Part**

```
<li>
    <a ng-click="increment()">>
    </a></li>
    <li>
    <input class="pageLocator" type="number" 
    ng-model="count" min="0" 
    ng-change="pageLocatorChange()">
    </li>
```

The problem is, view is getting updated when I just use the > button to increment the count property. The moment, I have changed the count property value from input field it stops getting update in input field when I click on > anchor tag but model is update.

All logic works except view getting update. Just the  part of view does not receive the update model. I do not know why?

More Information: After change event triggered from , it does not receive new value from click event.

More Update: The moment change event got activated, there is a count property created in this and input box binds to it (this.count). Changes in count does not affected to this.count so input box value does not change unless someone changes directly in the input box

I have fixed it by checking if there is a property called count in this then increment them grammatically.

```
$scope.increment = function()
      {
          $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
           if(this.count != undefined)
             {
             this.count ++;
             }

      }
```

Can anyone here please help me?

Comment: Try ng-keypress instead of ng-change on input.

Comment: No. Update on view works fine if I just use > to increment or change values through input field. The moment, I started to use both, displaying update value in input field is not working but model is getting update and all logics works good.

Comment: You don't need your function ng-change pageLocatorChange. Using ng-model with angular is enough, var is automatically updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment change event got activated, there is a property called count, got created in this and input box binds to it (this.count). Changes in $scope.count does not get reflected to this.count so input box value does not change unless someone changes directly in the input box

I have fixed it by checking if there is a property called count in this then increment them grammatically.

```
      $scope.increment = function()
      {
          $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
           if(this.count != undefined)
             {
             this.count ++;
             }

      }
```

If anyone here have better solution to this, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mismatched tags / variable name errors in your question. I've added the snippet below and everything is working as expected.

Click `HELLO` to incrent - then input to incrment/decrement

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller("QuizController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.count = 1;

  $scope.pageLocatorChange = function()
  {
       $scope.count = this.count;
  }

  $scope.increment = function()
  {
      $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
  }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='QuizController'>
 <a ng-click="increment()">HELLO</a>
 <li>
  <input class="pageLocator" type="number" 
    ng-model="count" min="0" 
    ng-change="pageLocatorChange()">
 </li>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is with <input> part does not receive the change.

Comment: Which browser are you using as it is working as expected for me

Comment: It is not browser. After change event, the view is not updating for click event because Angular doesn't know about these changes.

Comment: So this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3rvOPyIkYsxVnRGenBQV1ZvaTQ/view?usp=sharing is not the expected behaviour?

Comment: It is the expected behaviour. My problem did not get solved for some reasons. The moment change event got activated, there is a count property in this and input box binds to it. Changes in count does not affected to this.count so input box value does not change unless someone changes directly in the input box

Comment: Please check how I solved the problem. Can you check and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller("QuizController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.count = 1;

  $scope.pageLocatorChange = function()
  {
       $scope.count = this.count;
  }

  $scope.increment = function()
  {
      $scope.count ++;
  }

}]);



<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='QuizController'>
  <a ng-click="increment()">></a>
  <li>
   <input class="pageLocator" type="number" 
    ng-model="count" min="0" 
    ng-change="pageLocatorChange()">
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: No success :( The moment, I started to use both, displaying update value in input field is not working but model is getting update and all logics works good.

Comment: Please check the way in which I have solved the problem and give me some feedback or better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Angular update automatically your scope variable.

Then you don't need to call ng-change in your input.

And add a '$' at `scope` at `function($scope)`

Try without ng-change:

```
app.controller("QuizController", function ($scope) 
{
  $scope.count = 1;

  $scope.increment = function()
  {
      $scope.count++;
  }

}

<li>
   <a ng-click="increment()">
      >
   </a>
</li>
<li>
<input class="pageLocator" type="number" 
ng-model="count" min="0">
</li>
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/4472/)**

Comment: @forethought Look at my example

Comment: Yes. it works in your code. but it does not in mine. Changes are not getting reflected on view.

Comment: Please check the way in which I have solved the problem and give me some feedback or better solution.

Comment: @forethought you've always same errors. First add a $ at your $scope at the start. After delete your ng-change and your function. Try to do exactly same thing as my code